# Encryption software for Outlook that runs as a proxy, has a one-use scrtachpad and selectable key strength

Tags: windows, encryption, outlook

This encryption software needs to:

- run on Windows
- install a mail proxy that would run locally
- allow you to select the strength of your key up to 10240 bits
- has a one-use scratchpad for entropy
- possibly be made in Australia
- allow you to exchange keys through mail as well (not recommended)

Does anyone recall the name of the encryption software made in Australia, popular in the early 2000s? I can't recall the name for the life of me. The software was called something like mail-crypt or crypt-mail or secure-mail or mail-secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! [SecExMail](http://www.bytefusion.com/products/ens/secexmail/aboutsecexmail.htm). Last updated in 2010, though.

> As of February 2010, use of this product is now free of charge for commercial and private use.